# Android setRequestProperty in a url.openConnection()

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, illegalstateexception

I have an Android app that need to set a requestproperty in a connection. Here is my code:

```
 URL url = new URL(sUrl);

 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
 connection.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookievalue);
 connection.connect();
```

When I call the `setRequestProperty` method it launch the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made
```

Is there  a way to create the connection to the file without using the `url.openConnection()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the CookieManager mentioned in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Set your cookie to CookieManager

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("lang", "fr");
    cookie.setDomain("twitter.com");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setVersion(0);
    cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(new URI("http://twitter.com/"), cookie);
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Use url.openConnection() after you set your cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Here  `url.openCOnnection()`  will open new connection to the resource referred to by this URL.
Here you again opening a connection by calling  `url.connect()`  method. So remove that

Check [this..](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for the sample example...

Comment: The Exception is throwed in the sendRequestProperty line, not in the url.connect()