# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made" error in Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am new to Android and trying to get HTML content of a web page and that is when I came across this issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made
```

**Code :**

```
public static String getHTMLPage(String inputURL, String host, String referer, String cookie, String breakString) {

    String htmlContent = "";
    try {
        URL u = new URL(inputURL);
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        uc.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
        uc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        if (!referer.isEmpty()) {
            uc.setRequestProperty("Referer", referer);
        }
        uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "html");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");

        if (!cookie.isEmpty()) {
            uc.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!breakString.isEmpty() && line.contains(breakString)) {
                break;
            }
            htmlContent += line;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return htmlContent;
}
```

Basically, I have written this in a pure `java` application (where it is working fine) and I just wanted to re-use the same. I have googled and found few SO pages ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565195/android-setrequestproperty-in-a-url-openconnection),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320418/setrequestproperty-throwing-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-request),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765186/exception-cannot-set-request-property-after-connection-is-made-occurs-on-andro),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726195/setresponsecode-method-giving-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-method)), but none of them addresses the problem specific to `HTTPURLConnection` directly. (Though, some advised about `HTTPClient`, which is found to be deprecated which I don't want to use.)

Adding `getResponseCode()` is returning the value as 200 successfully.

```
System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE : "+uc.getResponseCode());
```

I have looked the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) page and which states

**public void setRequestProperty (String field, String newValue)**

> Sets the value of the specified request header field. The value will
>   only be used by the current URLConnection instance. This method can
>   only be called before the connection is established.

How I can set the request property before making the connections ? As per the code, we are getting the `HTTPURLConnection` object only after opening connection for a specific URL (and casting it with `HTTPURLConnection`)

```
         HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
```

What is the correct way to use `HTTPURLConnection` to read HTML page along with `setRequestProperty` ?

Answer (score 1):

The connection isn't created by 'URL.openConnection().` It is created when you get the input or error stream or the response code.

NB you shouldn't call `setDoOutput(true)` unless you are going to do output, which you aren't here. It sets the HTTP method to POST.

Comment: @ EJP : Without `setDoOutput` also, same issue. I forgot to remove those lines while posting here.

Comment: @ EJP : BTW, If connection is not created by `openConnection()` method, then why come it is throwing error as `Cannot set request property after connection is made`? What else I have to do to make it work ?

Comment: @Dinesh It doesn't, with the code you posted. You must have called something *else* that opens the connection. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30999890/207421).