# How to prevent openConnection() to actually connect

Tags: java, android, http, url

I want to use `HttpURLConnection` to connect to my webservice, POST an XML and get a result. I am using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Problem is, when I call the `setRequestProperty` method, it fails with an `IllegalStateException` saying I am "already connected". Apparently, `openConnection` in fact opens the connection to the URL (in my debugger, I can see the `connected` boolean set to `true`). According to the `URL` documentation of [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) though, it shouldn't. The [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) docs are unclear about it.

How do I prevent `openConnection` to connect, so I can set extra properties?

**Update** it looks like the `connection` is in some pool and doesn't get disconnected, not even after calling `connection.disconnect()`, or even killing the server.

I do not think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726195/setresponsecode-method-giving-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-method) as it gives no real answer. Also, the documentation seems to be unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setResponseCode method giving java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set method after connection is made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726195/setresponsecode-method-giving-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-method) and few others ...

Comment: @Selvin yes. That is more than three years old, and has no accepted answer. And the answers it does have, do not fix it.

Comment: then you should add bounty ... not repeat the question ... you wana newer? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147312/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-request-property-after-connection-i)

Comment: @Selvin that one is older

Comment: heheh ok :) just use setRequestProperty("connection", "close") (and maybe keep-alive false) in prev use of any connection in your app

Comment: @Selvin I'd love to, but no properties can be set anymore ...

Comment: so it is a first connection in the app?

Comment: It is correct to setRequestProperty() after openConnection(). However, before setting any meta data, make sure to set the desired http request method. In your case: connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

Comment: @Markus, `setDoOutput` takes care of that

Comment: and the API version of device is ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`openConnection()` does not connect, and the code you have posted does not behave as yu have described. What opens the TCP connection is any of the following:

- `getInputStream()`
- `getErrorStream()`
- `getResponseCode()`

*Ergo* you must have called one of those before trying to set a request property.

Comment: Is it possible the connection is in some pool? I had called one of those methods, but subsequent connections had the problem. I do have the `finally { connection.disconnect(); }` in place.

Comment: Suppose you post the real code, so we all know what you're talking about.

Comment: You should also call connection.close() to actually free-up the connection.

Comment: @Markus `connection.close()` does not exist

Comment: I thought it was a classic HttpConnection. Can you share the actual work flow? Eg. connect - writeXml - readResponse - close input stream - close output stream - disconnect - repeat